# Different View for 3.5 form factor in IB

Tags: ios, interface-builder

I'm on the verge of the desperation on this one.

I'm trying to design an audio player in iOS. Interface Builder with autolayout works great if at the end of the view you have a table with dynamic stuff that can fill the view, but in this case there is (from top to bottom, simplified):

- artwork
- title, etc.
- controls

I design for Retina 4-inch factor in IB. Applying the Retina 3.5 inch factor it's an unfixable mess.

Apparently I'm not able to let the two form factor co-exists in the same view for different reasons:

- controls does not attach themselves to the bottom of the view, they just go plain out probably due to the hardiness of the title and artwork view and various constraints. Setting content compression does not do absolutely nothing, like it does nothing setting manually height constraints.
- I have to keep a giant white space on 4-inch. This is disgusting and I tried to place some other info in that space that are visible only to 4-inch. Problem not solved however because #1.
- at some point I had something working but it was very subpar, even because artwork must be resized, etc.

So, instead of bashing my head against the wall and apply autoresizing and constraints that will be wiped the next time I move something, I'm asking if I can have in interface builder a different view for a particular controller, just for the 3.5 form factor since I can't take it anymore.

Comment: You can definitely get it to work, just need to learn how constraints work. Or alternatively, disable constraints and use the old style autoresize masks. Also beware some things have changed in iOS 7 as well so be sure to test that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you can, just click on the parent view of all this stuff (artwork etc.) and in the inspector pane change simulated metrics to iPhone 3.5 inch. See screenshot.

[image: simulated metrics]

---

**Update**

If you want to keep completely unrelated versions, then the easiest way is to copy the .xib file and add an extension to it. For example add "-568h" to the iPhone 5 version. Then you would have to load the corresponding .xib file in the `initWithNibName:` method.

This is actually how I am doing it:

[image]

Then in the .m file:

```
- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil
{
nibNameOrNil = IS_IPAD ? @"MainView~ipad" : IS_WIDESCREEN ? @"MainView-568h" : @"MainView";
.  
.  
.  
.  
}
```

And the macros I use:

```
#define IS_IPAD (UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM() == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPad)
#define IS_WIDESCREEN ( fabs( ( double )[ [ UIScreen mainScreen ] bounds ].size.height - ( double )568 ) < DBL_EPSILON )
```

Comment: I'm afraid this apparently doesn't do what I'm looking for, i.e. if I resize an image on 3.5 it will stay resized also on the 4 form factor. I'm asking if I can keep the two similar but unrelated with no code intervention. I guess this is not possible in IB. To further clarify I want to design a view controller for 3.5 and 4 with different views and different elements.

Comment: Interesting, thanks. How would I go to create a xib from this existing view controller? I have only my Main_iPhone.storyboard.

Comment: Oh, you use Storyboards. Then I would try creating two different "control" segues (for i4 and i5). Then you would have to hook the trigger (button..., in "list" segue) which shows the "control" segue to the "list" segue view controller directly and there decide which "control" segue you want to show. By "list" I mean a table with audio files (or anything you show before the controls/playback screen).